# identify book, 19th century science fiction

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is about the Chinese coming to a ravaged USA and contemplating the fate of the nation. Most likely written in the 19th century, or very early 20th century.

Comment: Was it a ["Yellow Peril"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Peril) propaganda story?

Comment: Not certain if it's a "Yellow Peril" story. It was mentioned in the same breath as The Last American: A Fragment From The Journal of Khan-Li, which I did enjoy, and my colleague has yet to identify the book several months later.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot, but could it be [*The Battle of the Wabash: A Letter From the Invisible Police?*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GkdMAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA364&dq=the+battle+of+the+wabash+letter+invisible+police&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAmoVChMI0b-XmZW1xwIVwoI-Ch2X7A9Z#v=onepage&q=the%20battle%20of%20the%20wabash%20letter%20invisible%20police&f=false) It is written as a "found manuscript" and tells how America is taken over by the Chinese. Published in *The Californian,* October 1880. The author is identified only as "Lorelle".

Comment: My friend mentioned the story/book in passing. I pinged him a few times for identification but he never got an answer. This answer is as good as any. Much obliged!